# SQL select ordered randomly, but certain rows must be grouped by a 'next' id column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `next`. Both would be the SHA256 of a file, `id` being the primary key, and `next` being nullable, referencing another row's `id`.

What I'm trying to do is select the rows from a table ordered randomly, but at the same time: if a row contains a value in `next`, the next row's id/pk MUST be the value of `next`, from the previous row. It would essentially be a random query, but keeping certain rows that depend on each other in a sequence.

The random part would be easy, just something like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand()`, but I didn't found anything about ordering based on a previous row's value. Another option would be manually sorting in the client, after the query, but that might be too costly depending on the table's size.

Example:

| id | next |
| --- | --- |
| a | null |
| b | c |
| c | d |
| d | null |
| e | null |
| f | null |
| g | null |
| h | e |
| i | null |

Expected result:

| id | next |
| --- | --- |
| f | null |
| i | null |
| h | e |
| e | null |
| b | c |
| c | d |
| d | null |
| g | null |
| a | null |

(Note that the results are shuffled, but `h` is followed by `e`, `b` is followed by `c`, which is followed by `d`)

Is it possible to so such a query in SQLite?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph walking problem.  I assume that your structure is a set of linked lists:

- No cycles.
- `next` is unique

These assumptions are based on your naming.

With this assumption, you can use a relatively simple recursive CTE to construct the path to each `id` and then order by that path:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, next, cast(id as text)  as path
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.next = t.id)
      union all
      select t.id, t.next, (cte.path || coalesce('->' || t.id, ''))
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.next = t.id
     )
select id, next
from cte
order by path;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9959787c7fb79d15c68f4557875e25b5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: `.. select id, next, cast(id as text)  as path, random() as r .. order by r, path` I thihk to shuffle the results as OP required.

Comment: Seems to work very well! I'm just starting in SQL, and a recursive query like this is very interesting. And with @Serg comment it's also shuffled. Thanks!